# How can I send a JAXB-marshalled object as a parameter using the Jetty client API?

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

...practically I'm looking for a REST-style EJB-or-SOAP-replacement ;)

---

### This enables me to receive an JAXB-marshalled object from server

#### Client side

```
WebResource r = client.resource("http://localhost:9999/resource1");

SomeObject in = r.post(SomeObject.class);
```

#### Server side

```
@Path("/")
public static final class TestResource {
    @Path("resource1")
    @POST
    public SomeObject resource1() {
        return new SomeObject("Object1");
    }
}
```

---

### Here's an example how to send a JAXB-marshalled object...

**...when it's the only (unnamed) parameter.**
I don't even know if this behavior is intended to work. One thing doesn't work this way: when the client uses `client.addFilter(new GZIPContentEncodingFilter())`, the server doesn't understand the request, even when all other (usual) gzipped requests are fine.

#### Client side

```
WebResource r = client.resource("http://localhost:9999/resource2");

SomeObject out = new SomeObject("no name");

SomeObject in = r.post(SomeObject.class, out /*!!!*/);
```

#### Server side

```
@Path("/")
public static final class TestResource {
    @Path("resource2")
    @POST
    public SomeObject resource2(SomeObject o) {
        o.setName("NEW NAME!"); // "modify" object
        return o; // send back
    }
}
```

Again, this behavior seems not consistent or even not intended to work. Why else should the gzip content encoding filter fail here? **Can anyone comment on this?**

---

### But how can I *send* such an object as a request *parameter*?

#### Client side

```
WebResource r = client.resource("http://localhost:9999/resource3");

SomeObject out = new SomeObject("no name"); // this would be the sent param
r. /* some magic method to add a JAXB-marshalled object as parameter */ (out);

SomeObject in = r.post(SomeObject.class); // this receives the "modified" object
```

#### Server side

```
@Path("/")
public static final class TestResource {
    @Path("resource3") // ??? have something to happen to the URI?
    @POST
    // which kinds of Param? Path? Query? Form? Matrix? Something else?
    public SomeObject resource3(@PathParam("a") SomeObject o) {
        o.setName("NEW NAME!"); // "modify" object
        return o; // send back
    }
}
```